# Getting these errors when trying to write to excel file form mltidi-array?

Tags: java, excel, eclipse, multidimensional-array, apache-poi

```
 for (int f=0; f<9621; f++)
                {
                  Row row1 = sheet.createRow(f);
                           for (int g=0; g<4875; g++){
                                Cell cell = row1.createCell(g);
                                cell.setCellValue((String) row[f][g] );// line 155
```

> > Blockquote Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space   at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.resize(Saver.java:1700)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.preEmit(Saver.java:1303)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emit(Saver.java:1190)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.emitElement(Saver.java:962)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.processElement(Saver.java:476)
> >       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver.process(Saver.java:307)     at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Saver$TextSaver.saveToString(Saver.java:1864)
> >       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor._xmlText(Cursor.java:546)
> >       at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cursor.xmlText(Cursor.java:2436)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.xmlText(XmlObjectBase.java:1500)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.getKey(SharedStringsTable.java:134)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xssf.model.SharedStringsTable.addEntry(SharedStringsTable.java:180)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:453)
> >       at
> >     org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell.setCellValue(XSSFCell.java:417)
> >       at files.EXP.main(EXP.java:155)

Answer (score 1):

Use stream writing in case if you have a lot of data:

https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf